# PHP sending email with attachement

Tags: php, email, attachment

I'm trying to send an email with an attachment in PHP 8 and, whilst it sends the email with the attachment okay, the attachments all come out as corrupted for the recipient. I've tried jpg, png and pdf and they all come out corrupted.

Worked fine with PHP 7.4 and previous but doesn't seem to work with PHP 8.
What has changed?

Here is the code -
Note: the other mail variables $recipient_email,$subject,$message are set prior to this code.

```
   $mime_boundary="==Multipart_Boundary_x".md5(mt_rand())."x";  

   $tmp_name1 = $_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'];
   $type1 = $_FILES['attachment']['type'];
   $name1 = $_FILES['attachment']['name'];
   $size1 = $_FILES['attachment']['size'];

   if (file_exists($tmp_name1)){
    if(is_uploaded_file($tmp_name1)){
     $file1 = fopen($tmp_name1,'rb');
     $data1 = fread($file1,filesize($tmp_name1));
     fclose($file1);
     $data1 = chunk_split(base64_encode($data1));
    }

    $headers = "From: $myname <$mymail>\r\n" .
         "Reply-To: <$mymail>\r\n" .
         "Return-Path: <$mymail>\r\n";  
         "X-Mailer: PHP\r\n" .
         "Disposition-Notification-To: ".$mymail." <$bcc>\r\n";

    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n" .
         "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\r\n" .
         " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";

    $body = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" .
         "--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
         "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"utf-8\"\n" .
         "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" .
         $message . "\n\n";

    $body .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
         "Content-Type: {$type1};\n" .
         " name=\"{$name1}\"\n" .
         $data1 . "\n\n" .
         "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n";

    $body .= "--{$mime_boundary}--\n";

   mail($recipient_email,$subject,$body,$headers,"-f ".$mymail);
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you do not use proper libraries? Like PHPMailer? It will handle all tidy work for you

Comment: Still using `mail` for sending complex emails? (“The 1990s called and want their tech stack back…”) Use a proper library made for such things, such as PHPMailer or Swift Mailer.

Comment: I don't like using external code that I cannot either understand or debug in case there are security holes.
Fortunately this code I use is in an admin area and nobody else has access to it other than me.

Answer (score 0):

DOH, silly me.I had two lines of code transposed.
Should be this at the end -

```
         "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" .
         $data1 . "\n\n";
```

Instead of -

```
         $data1 . "\n\n" .
         "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n";
```